# Vertica backup ssh port

Tags: backup, vertica

I am using Vertica backup script /opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py.

Unfortunately it fails when it tries to connect to the host via ssh on default 22 port.

The problem is that we use on our server 222 port. I have changed that in the backup .ini file by adding following setting:

```
[Transmission]
encrypt= False
port_ssh_backup = 222
```

Unfortunately script still uses port 22:

```
preparing on host 127.0.0.1...
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
Unable to ssh to host: 127.0.0.1
backup failed!
```

How to overwrite default port? I use 7.1.1 Vertica version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that option doesn't work with 7.1.1. I had to define that port in Python backup script: /opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py